# Api WooCommerce obtener datos de Facturación

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Como Puedo obtener los datos de facturación con la api rest de woocommerce???

```
<?php print_r($woocommerce->get('products/794')); ?>
```

esta consulta no me trae los datos de facturación como puedo obtener esos datos??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes pedir [todas las orders que incluyan cierto producto](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-orders) pasándole el id de producto en el array de parámetros y fijarte [los datos asociados a cada item](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#order-line-items-properties) ( los productos incluidos en la order ), algo así:

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
  $_ENV['WC_URL'],
  $_ENV['WC_CONSUMER_KEY'],
  $_ENV['WC_CONSUMER_SECRET'],
  [
    'version' => 'wc/v3',
  ]
);

$product_ID = 3307;
$params = [
  'product' => $product_ID,
  // 'status' => 'completed' // default 'pending'
];

$orders = $woocommerce->get( "orders", $params );

//var_dump( $orders );
foreach( $orders as $order ){
  $order_ID = $order->id;
  $order_status = $order->status;
  $order_items = $order->line_items;
  echo "[{$order_ID}][$order_status]---- order_items ----" . PHP_EOL;
  // var_dump( $order_items );

  foreach ( $order_items as $item ){
    $item_id = $item->id;
    $item_Pid = $item->product_id;

    // para filtrar la data de sólo el producto que nos interesa
    if ( $item_Pid === $product_ID ) {
      $item_Vid = $item->variation_id;
      $item_name = $item->name;
      $item_subtotal = $item->subtotal;
      $item_total = $item->total;

      echo "[{$item_id}]---- item ----" . PHP_EOL;
      echo "product id {$item_Pid}" . PHP_EOL;
      echo "product variation {$item_Vid}" . PHP_EOL;
      echo "product name: {$item_name}" . PHP_EOL;
      echo "subtotal: {$item_subtotal}" . PHP_EOL;
      echo "total: {$item_total}" . PHP_EOL;

      // datos extra vienen aquí
      $item_metadata = $item->meta_data;
      echo "[{$item_id}]---- item_metadata ----" . PHP_EOL;
      // var_dump( $item_metadata );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: excelente, pero con eso puedo obtener los datos del formulario de pago, donde pones la direccion, telefono cosas asi????

Comment: depende de si son datos de [billing](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#order-billing-properties) o de [shipping](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#order-shipping-properties) van a estar en uno u otro lado, un `var_dump` de la order siempre ayuda a encontrar cosas. hay datos q son específicos del cliente y otros q son específicos del producto que no vienen en la order y hay que pedirlos via `/products/id` o `/customers/id` según sea el caso

Comment: Pero supongo que todo esta relacionado con el id de la orden, lo que sucede Alo, es que lo estoy haciendo con Laravel, use el plugin de corcel, pero fracase en el intento , probare con el codigo que dices y con lo que me comentas muchas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda, agregando a esto son datos de billing

Comment: para hacer pruebas rápidas a que endpoint pegarle y con que data podes hacer un `composer init` en una carpeta e incluir el `automattic/woocommerce` como dependencia ( en este ejemplo que arme usé también el phpdotenv pero por costumbre nomas ) ; luego por línea de comando vas haciendo `php wcApiTest.php` luego de cada edit/var_dump ( la doc del api es medio escueta en ejemplos ) contrastas esa data con lo que ves en la db o el backend de wordpress y va saliendo